# What exactly does XML schema component maxLength mean?

Tags: xml, xsd

Does the XML schema component `xs:maxLength` refer to the length of the encoded value (possibly containing entities like `&amp;` or `&apos;`) or the unencoded value of an XML element? Does the character encoding have any significance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the number of Unicode code points after any whitespace normalization requested by the `whiteSpace` facet. Entities such as `&amp;` (or `&myBoilerPlatePara;`) are expanded before the characters are counted. Surrogate pairs count as one character, not two.

Answer (score 1):

As specified in [Validation Rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#cvc-maxLength-valid), the interpretation of this facet is dependent on the value space. [Here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xml-schema/0596002521/re35.html) is another good explanation of the above.

Keeping the above in perspective, the actual value of the xsd:string (say) would be considered, not the encoded value as the value space comparison in this case needs to happen with the actual content of the type, not the encoded form.